# How do i change text of form menu item from another forms button

Tags: c#

I was not able to locate an answer on stackoverflow so here it goes. I am attempting to change the text of a MenuStrip subitem when clicking a button on a sub form. Below is the code from my Submit button on my sub form. when clicked it should change the text of "Log In" to "Log Out". Code seems fine and no errors but does not update the text.

```
public AccessForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtUser.Text == "admin" && txtPass.Text == "1234")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Access granted.", "Access");

            playgroundPlannersForm mainForm = new playgroundPlannersForm();

            mainForm.logInToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Log Out";
            this.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", "Warning");
            txtUser.Clear();
            txtPass.Clear();
            txtUser.Focus();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message: " + ex, "Error");
    }
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: you almost have the right idea.. for starters I would create a property and then depending on the structure of your application/Form.. I would also look into MDI using Parent / Owner when creating the instance of the other form and doing a check or Switch statement based on the Button Text there are several ways you could accomplish this

Comment: Please don't try to do things like this. There should be some underlying object model that controls things like the state of menu items. You can change that in your subform and your main form can react. Do *not* try to change UI elements across forms or controls. The code will become unmanageable very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of the main form and changing that; you need to be passing along the reference to the original form and using that to update it.

Here's one way to do it. In your sub form.. add this property:

```
public playgroundPlannersForm ParentForm { get; set; }
```

..then, in your code above, use this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Access granted.", "Access");

//playgroundPlannersForm mainForm = new playgroundPlannersForm(); <--- not needed anymore

ParentForm.logInToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Log Out";
```

In your main form, before you show your subform.. do this:

```
SubForm subform = new SubForm();
subform.ParentForm = this;
subform.Show();
```

That sets the parent to the form that's creating it (which, according to your code, is the correct form). You may also need to go into your form designer code and make the loginToolStripMenuItem public (if it isn't already).